# Hover part of the image to see div

Tags: html, css

I want to have such text on hover on green yellow or blue selection.I understand it's quite complicated(even with html5 and css3 which is not cross browser compatible), because there are 3d shapes in image.So I think it would be cool to at least be able to hover one of rectangles and then to see hover text as in example below.

Any ideas how to do it nicely only with html/css

I tried some image maps, also to change the possition of invisible div to become visible on hover but that didn't work that well

[image: Graph]

Comment: If you're happy with imperfect hover targets, take a look (at the code) here for inspiration: http://www.joyent.com/products/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Going a step beyond paislee's answer we can do this which will be compatible to IE8 and allow for much nicer styling than a `title` tooltip. It can be styled with CSS and required no javascript to display:

Like So: http://jsfiddle.net/DVWkT/

Edit: hehe, I'm having some fun with this... as you'll notice, we can change the posiitoning and have the item that displays on hover display well outside of the bounds of the parent. http://jsfiddle.net/DVWkT/2/

```
#myImage {
    position: relative;
    background: url(image.url);
    width: /**image width*/;
    height: /**image height*/;
}

#innerHover {
    position: absolute;
    top: /**distance from top of image */;
    left: /**distance from left of image */;
    width: /**region width*/;
    height: /**region height*/;
}
#popupdiv{
    //style however you like
}
#innerHover #popupdiv{
   display:none;
}
#innerHover:hover #popupdiv{
    display:block;
}
```

With html like this:

```
<div id="myImage">
    <div id="innerHover" title="hover text"><div id="popupdiv">Fancy pop up content with no javascript! And it's backwards compatible to IE8!</div></div>
</div>
```

Comment: And if you uses classes instead of ids for `innerHover` and `popupDiv`, then you can use them more than once on a page, with only `myImageN` unique CSS per image.  it should still be OK with IE8.

Answer (score 1):

### **Position elements relative to the image, using `title` for hover text:**

**Markup:**

```
<div id="myImage">
    <div id="innerHover" title="hover text"></div>
</div>
```

**Styles:**

```
#myImage {
    position: relative;
    background: url(image.url);
    width: /**image width*/;
    height: /**image height*/;
}

#innerHover {
    position: absolute;
    top: /**distance from top of image */;
    left: /**distance from left of image */;
    width: /**region width*/;
    height: /**region height*/;
}
```

### **Or for customized hover text, you might do it with css `opacity`:**

**Markup:**

```
<div id="myImage">
    <div id="innerHover">Hover text</div>
</div>
```

**Styles:**

```
#myImage {
    /** same as above */
}

#innerHover {
    /** same as above, plus custom text styles, plus: */
    opacity:0.0;
    filter:alpha(opacity=0);
}

#innerHover:hover {
    opacity:1.0;
    filter:alpha(opacity=100); /** no transparency on hover */
}
```

- [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/XbjMz/)
- [Opacity reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/opacity)